# determine if the given function is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if the given function is a linear transformation.$T : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ with T(v)= $[0  ...  0]$

My thought process on solving this:
I know that in order to be a linear transformation, the following 2 conditions must be met:

1. $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$
2. $T(cu) = cT(u)$

I'm new to linear transformations, and I'm confused on how to set this up.

Comment: What you need to check is whether $0+0=0$ and $c\cdot 0=0$... ;)

Comment: So $T$( 0 ... 0 + 0 ... 0) = $T$(0 ... 0) + $T$ (0  ... 0 ) and  $T$(c*0) = c(0)

Comment: Then I get 0 + 0 = 0 and c$*$ 0 = 0

Comment: @Theo Am I right?

Comment: @musk $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary vectors in the statement of $1$, you cannot assume they are both $\vec 0$. What you wrote is correct but not what is required to prove $T$ is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are told $T(anything)=\vec 0$.

So what is $T(u+v)$? Then what is $T(u)$? $T(v)$? Is it true $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$?

If you are told what $T$ does explicitly, you can calculate both sides of the equality to see if they are the same. In this case, $T$ will be linear.

If you think one of the equalities may not be true, just find any vectors or scalar that fail to satisfy either 1) or 2) and provide it as a counter-example (showing $T$ is not a linear transformation).

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot :)